# Create anchor tag with route contain under @php script in blade template

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-8, laravel-blade

Route is not working. How can I write an anchor tag based on some condition? If the condition is true then the anchor tag will be printed with the route. I wrote the code below, but I get an error.

In my blade template:

```
@php
    if (SOMECONDATION) {
        echo '<a href="{{ route('my.route') }}">Approve</a>';
    }   
@endphp
```

Comment: what is the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`{{ }}` is `echo`-ing. You can use this :

```
@if($p->name == 0)
<a href="{{ route('my.route') }}">Approve</a>
@endif
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to use echo or anything. Directly use @if @endif and for route use {{ }}

```
    @if($condition)
     <a href="{{ route('something') }}">Approve</a>
   @endif
```